# firebase dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class) returns null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Trying to get "Dio" from char_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYHqv.png)

```
private View.OnClickListener saveBtnList;
    {
        saveBtnList = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                characterName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.charNameXML);
                str = characterName.getText().toString();

                DatabaseReference ref = charNameDatabaseReference.child("User/char_data");

                if(str.length() > 0) {
                    final CharacterInfoAdapter CIAdapter = new CharacterInfoAdapter(str);
                    charNameDatabaseReference.child("User/char_data").setValue(CIAdapter);

                    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            String value = dataSnapshot.child("User/char_data").getValue(String.class);
                            System.out.println("You ight... Character Name is: " + value);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            System.out.println("You Thought :3");
                        }
                    });

                }
                saved = true;
                intent = new Intent(basic_info.this, character_select.class);
            }
        };
    }
```

The issue that I run into is that I can update the database but can’t pull the information as it always returns null. If I use String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class) I get a cannot convert Hash to String error.

Comment: Please add your database structure and the exact data you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String value = null;
    for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        value = postSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
    }
    System.out.println("You ight... Character Name is: " + value);
}
```

----instead of------

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String value = dataSnapshot.child("User/char_data").getValue(String.class);
                        System.out.println("You ight... Character Name is: " + value);
                    }
```